# How to extract the name of immediate directory with the filename using lastIndexOf method?

Tags: java

I want to extract the name of immediate directory with the filename. For example 
c:/wallpapers/images/images.gif I just want to retrieve images/images.gif. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String shortenedPath(String path) {
  File complete = new File(path);
  String parentDir = complete.getParent().getName();
  File shortened = new File(parentDir, complete.getName());
  return shortened.toString();
}
```